# Полнотекстовый поиск по значению "de" в mySQL

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

В поле language VARCHAR(2) содержится двухбковенная аббревиатура языка.

Пытаюсь вывести все записи с немецким языком:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`language`) AGAINST("de");
```

Почему-то именно для значения "de" это выражение возвращает пустой набор, хотя не нашел "de" в списке зарезервированных слов.

В настройках mySQL задал ft_min_word_len=1. Для остальных "языков" проблем не наблюдаю.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: а зачем вам в поле из двух символов полностекстовый поиск вообще? сделайте индекс по полю и юзайте обычное сравнение.

Comment: так не пойдет. Потому, что SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`language`) AGAINST("de ru th ua ..."); Но мой вопрос не в этом

Comment: кроме `lang = 'ru'` можно написать и `lang in ('ru', 'en')` или `lang = 'ru' or lang='en`. вопрос ваш не в этом, да. но сдается мне, вы выбрали не тот инструмента для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово `de` присутствует [в штатном списке stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) для `innoDB`. Слова из этого  списка игнорируются в поисковом запросе - таким образом вы задали пустой поисковый запрос.

Есть задокументированная возможность переопределить таблицу stopword, но для указанной в вопросе и комментарии задаче вовсе не нужен fulltext поиск.

Comment: Как вы думаете, для каких целей innoDB резервирует и игнорирует stopwords  в механизме полнотекстового поиска? не могу понять. Иначе говоря, почему бы не разрешить использовать эти слова в части AGAINST("...")?

Comment: `A stopword is a word such as “the” or “some” that is so common that it is considered to have zero semantic value.` как пояснено на соседней странице https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html